# Getting column does not exist error in postgresql sql table

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-constant

I have an sql table that looks like this in postgresql called `test`.

```
    date    |  data   |      source      
------------+---------+------------------
 2015-09-23 | 128     | aaamt
 2015-09-24 | 0       | aaamtx2
.....
```

I type `SELECT * FROM test where source="aaamt"` but I get the following error,

```
ERROR:  column "aaamt" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM test where source = "aaamt";
```

Why am I getting this error and how to I fix it?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use `single quote` instead of `double quote`

```
SELECT * FROM test where source = 'aaamt'
```

Answer (score 1):

Double quotes indicate to Postgres that you are trying to specify an *identifier* such as a column or table name.  Use single quotes for string literals, and your query should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE source = 'aaamt';
```

To be clear here, you current query is basically being interpreted as this:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE source = aaamt;
```

Here `aaamt` is being treated as a column name or maybe some other database identifier, but not as a string literal.